# using TikZ with multipage table

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions, longtable

I am using `tikz` files to insert figures . 
I would like to add 3 figures one after the other with the same figure caption:

I use this code: the problem is that the last figure is at the bottom of the page and half of it is missing. How do I put it in the next page with a caption :  `... continued from previous page ...`

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{longtable}{c}
\subfigure[]{\input{VD1m.tikz}}  \\\ 
\subfigure[]{\input{VD1m.tikz}} \\\ 
\subfigure[]{\input{VD1m.tikz}} \\\
\end{longtable}
\caption{this are my figures (a)subfigure1  (b) subfigure2 (c) Ssubfigure3 }
\label{VD1m}
```

Comment: you can't. Tikz pictures do not break unless you pull off tedious tricks.. you don't need subfigure if they are not floats just let them as they are and hope that longtable handles it..

Comment: I don't want to break the picture, I want the whole picture to move to the next page. I use subfigure because I want to have (a) and (b) and (c) at the bottom of each figure/picture so I can refer to them in a single caption.

Comment: I would like to add that the caption of the figure is missing does not appear not even on the next page

Comment: Figures are floats. If you place them inside a table then they can't float. You can put them in the required format inside a figure environment.

Comment: But how do I do it? How do I put 2 figures in one page  with (a) and (b) at the bottom of the figures.  and have the caption at the bottom of the second figure in the first page. and have another figure ( or 2 ) at the next page with a caption that reads: Figure 1: continue from previous page

Answer (score 1):

Probably [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package can do it, but I've never used. With [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) class is as easy as (some comments inside code)

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{mwe} %Don't need it, included to provide images.
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure} %Now figure float will have subfloat captions

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\subbottom{Subfigure a)}

\includegraphics{example-image-b}
\subbottom{Subfigure b)}

\caption{These are my figures a, b and c}
\end{figure}

%You have to break your float where you want (or need). LaTeX won't do it for you.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image-c}
\subbottom{Subfigure c)}

%\contcaption will use same figure number from previous \caption command.
\contcaption{continue from previous page}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]